# Squid: How do I rewrite server to my server?

Tags: ubuntu, squid

i am working with squid proxy on  ubuntu, i have created a rewrite rule:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
$|=1;
while (<>) {
    my @inputs=split / /;
    chomp($inputs[0]);
    if ($inputs[0] =~ q|THE SERVER|) {
        print 'MY SERVER'."\n";
    } else {
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

So The Problem is that when i use my proxy to go to "THE SERVER" It just says proxy isn't setup right... It doesn't show "MYSERVER".
The config can be found here: http://pastebin.com/DJgcQwps
This rule is passed by: url_rewrite_program /etc/squid3/rewrite.pl

Comment: please show the squid config where you call this script

Comment: @robin-green http://pastebin.com/DJgcQwps

Comment: what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: this is on my server, i use the proxy in google chrome, google chrome doesn't load anything however if i remove url_rewrite_program /etc/squid3/rewrite.pl from the conf file, the proxy works.

Comment: please post the output of `http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:port/ curl -v http://the.server` in your question

Comment: * About to connect() to proxy MYIP port 3128 (#0)
*   Trying MYIP...
* Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0  if i remove  url_rewrite_program /etc/squid3/rewrite.pl it connects perfectly...

Comment: check your log files, this is a config error and is offtopic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

`MY SERVER` should be a full URL, not just a domain name.

Comment: the http:// is there, stackoverflow makes it a link :/ it is http:// myserverip/test.html without the space